# Way to restore database in 'noarchivelog' mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, restore

My database(Oracle 11g) is in 'nonarchivelog' mode. Now, I'm encountering an issue with my database server. Unfortunately, I don't have any database backup as well as VM back up of last two days. I'm totally fed up and I need a way to bring back my database to previous state. Do I have an option to restore my database using datafiles and control files? Are there any possible ways to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the exact issue that you have encountered?

Comment: Server was crash due to some reason where the DB is running. Now, I need to recover my database on other machine. Do I have an option for this?

Comment: If you have the online redo log files, control files, parameter file and data files then. First install same version of oracle software on new host then you can copy these files to new host. You may start your database from there.

Comment: So the instance was running at the time that the system crashed, and is now refusing to start because of detected inconsistencies?

Comment: Yes David. DB is now refusing to start.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response JSapkota. But I have a doubt, while installing the DB on other host do i need to use the same file names and service name for the DB or I can use a different one?

Comment: And when I install the DB, control files, system files and undo files get created automatically. If I replace them blindly with my old DB files, does they work properly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't know why you can't open this database in the current host and its not clear what kind of recovery is required for the database to open. According to your comment-"Server was crash due to some reason where the DB is running. Now, I need to recover my database on other machine. Do I have an option for this?"-  I am assuming that you want to migrate this database to new host.

If it is required to recover the database( as you have said, "DB is now refusing to start", then moving these datafiles into another database doesn't help. It still asks you to recover it. If so then visit this documentation-[Recovering a Database in NOARCHIVELOG Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/osrecov.htm#BRADV219).

If your host is no longer capable of running this database and you are going to start this database to new host then I have small demonstration for this purpose.

I have two hosts, namely `server1` and `server2`. In `server1`, I have installed Oracle Database 11g R2 wihtout Grid Infrastrcture and created one database called `orcl`. The directory structure for required files are as follows-

1) Spfile: - `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`

2) Controlfiles/Redolog files/Datafiles: `$ORACLE_BASE/oradata/orcl/`

Now I am going the crash the database using `SHUT ABORT` command.

```
[oracle@server1 Desktop]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sat Jan 28 04:21:18 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
READ WRITE


SQL> create table test(id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> shut abort;
```

In `server2`, I have installed same version of OS(Oracle Linux) and Oracle Database 11g(Software only). I have created the following directories as well.

1) Audit Dest: `$ORACLE_BASE/admin/orcl/adump`

2) Controlfiles/Redolog files/Datafiles Dest: `$ORACLE_BASE/oradata/orcl`

Next, I am going to copy these files to `server2`.

```
[oracle@server1 oradata]$ scp -r orcl  oracle@192.168.30.132:/u01/app/oracle/oradata
oracle@192.168.30.132's password: 
users01.dbf                                   100% 5128KB   5.0MB/s   00:01    
redo01.log                                    100%   50MB  50.0MB/s   00:00    
redo03.log                                    100%   50MB  25.0MB/s   00:02    
sysaux01.dbf                                  100%  470MB  29.4MB/s   00:16    
control01.ctl                                 100% 9520KB   9.3MB/s   00:00    
redo02.log                                    100%   50MB  25.0MB/s   00:02    
temp01.dbf                                    100%   20MB  20.0MB/s   00:00    
control02.ctl                                 100% 9520KB   9.3MB/s   00:00    
undotbs01.dbf                                 100%   30MB  15.0MB/s   00:02    
system01.dbf                                  100%  740MB  20.6MB/s   00:36
```

I have also copied the spfile and password files to the same location as it was on server1.

```
[oracle@server1 dbs]$ scp spfileorcl.ora orapworcl oracle@192.168.30.132:$ORACLE_HOME/dbs
oracle@192.168.30.132's password: 
spfileorcl.ora                                100% 2560     2.5KB/s   00:00    
orapworcl                                     100% 1536     1.5KB/s   00:00
```

After the completion I tried to start the database.

```
[oracle@server2 u01]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sat Jan 28 04:35:59 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  730714112 bytes
Fixed Size          2256832 bytes
Variable Size         482345024 bytes
Database Buffers      243269632 bytes
Redo Buffers            2842624 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Now lets try to select from the table created before.

```
SQL> select * from test;

    ID
----------
     1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the wide description. But I need 1 more clarification. What I understood is, I should install same version of db in server2 and copy & replace its control file, data files and parameter files(which are created by default during its installation) with these files from server1. Then, I need to start my DB using these files. Am I right?

Comment: @SHS: As I have said, "In server2, I have installed same version of OS(Oracle Linux) and Oracle Database 11g(Software only).." yes.